# How to upload file into a specific folder on Backblaze?

Tags: javascript, backblaze

Yò! So I've followed [this guide on Backblaze and JavaScript](https://itnext.io/backblaze-b2-pros-cons-and-how-to-use-it-with-javascript-8c2d2a9a69d9). I've successfully uploaded files on my Backblaze bucket, but I can't find a way to define a folder where to upload the files.

I've also checked the documentation and it mentions folders but not in the contest of uploading files. Does someone know how to?

```
{
  axios
    .post(
      credentials.apiUrl + "/b2api/v1/b2_get_upload_url",
      {
        bucketId: bucketId,
      },
      { headers: { Authorization: credentials.authorizationToken } }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      var uploadUrl = response.data.uploadUrl;
      var uploadAuthorizationToken = response.data.authorizationToken;
      const fileSize = file.byteLength;

      var sha1 = crypto.createHash("sha1").update(file).digest("hex");

      axios
        .post(uploadUrl, file, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: uploadAuthorizationToken,
            "X-Bz-File-Name": fileName,
            "Content-Type": "b2/x-auto",
            "Content-Length": fileSize,
            "X-Bz-Content-Sha1": sha1,
            "X-Bz-Info-Author": "unknown",
          },
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response); // successful response
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err); // an error occurred
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
    });
};
```

Comment: Omg. My only hope just crumbled down. Please how did you send the file? was it as a buffer ? Was it the file url? Please what did you do

Comment: `let image = await (
  await axios({ url: imageUrl, responseType: "arraybuffer" })
 ).data;` Maybe this could help, that's how I got the image through a request, this can be then uploaded on Backblaze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I feel pretty stupid. The solution is simply:

```
"X-Bz-File-Name": "folderName/" + fileName,
```

This will also create all the necessary directories.
Yò.

Comment: FYI this works even without previously creating the directory. In my case I'm creating 12 nested directories (the first 12 characters from a sha1) for each file I'm uploading and they're created automatically upon upload.